# Why create arraylist outside default constructor but then assign it in the construtor? What does this do?

Tags: java

Why create arraylist outside default constructor but then assign it in the construtor? What does this do? Couldnt you create it all within the constructor or outside of it?

Here is a piece example i saw:

```
public class Tickets {

public ArrayList <movie> movies;  


public Tickets() {
    
    movies = new ArrayList <movie>(); //assigning movie to array list
}
```

Comment: *"Why create arraylist outside default constructor but then assign it in the construtor?"* - because you're not (creating an instance of `ArrayList`) until the constructor is called. All you're doing is defining an instance variable for the class, which, until it's assigned a value, will be `null` by default

Comment: This is an example of the fairly common failure to understand the difference between an object and a variable.

Comment: It is part of a strange fashion shared by parts of the JDK and some IDEs for separating the declaration from the initialization. Do not imitate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Three distinct parts: variable declaration, instantiation, and reference assignment

You asked:

> Why create arraylist outside default constructor but then assign it in the construtor?

Your question is based on a misunderstanding.

The line:

```
public ArrayList <movie> movies;
```

… does *not* create an `ArrayList` [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)). That line  defines a variable that *will* hold, but does not yet hold, a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to an `ArrayList` object. Holding no reference means the value of this variable is [*null*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer).

That line created a receptacle, but did not fill it.

Your `new ArrayList <movie>()` code creates an `ArrayList` object. That object lives in memory. That code returns a *reference* to that new object (effectively its [address in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address), a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))).

Your `movies =` code  captures that returned reference (the quasi memory location) and stores it in your variable, for later use in your other code.

---

In your specific example, you could just as well have combined the variable declaration with the instantiation and the reference assignment. No need for your constructor then, as it performed no other work.

You can omit the parameterized type when instantiating. The compiler can deduce that from the type you specified when declaring the object reference variable. So `new ArrayList<>()` rather than `new ArrayList<movie>()`.

Add the keyword `final` if you want to prevent replacement of your list instance with another.

```java
public class Tickets {

    public final ArrayList <movie> movies = new ArrayList <> () ;

}
```

---

By the way, your `movie` class should be spelled `Movie`. Class names start with an uppercase letter, variable names start with a lowercase letter. So `Movie`, not `movie`.

And generally best to declare your variables as a more general super-type when you don't need to explicitly refer to features exclusive to the more specific sub-type. So, `List`, not `ArrayList`.

```java
public class Tickets {

    public final List < Movie > movies = new ArrayList <> () ;

}
```